# jquery remove/ select element from class by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove some elements with class by the index. Let me introduce.

First, I create some divs, giving them class and an element after getting result from ajax.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myphp.php",
            data: {label: label},
            success: function(result) {

                    var data ="";
                    for (i = 0; i<result.item.length; i++){
                        var data = result.item[i].data;
                        var div = $("<div class ='item'></div>");
                        var divData= "<p class ='divData' > "+ divData+"</p>";
                       }
                },
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(xhr){
                console.log("error");
            }
      });
```

Then, I want to remove all unnecessary divs with class = "detail" by clicking the necessary one.

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.detail', function() {
    var numItems = $('.detail').length;
    for ( i = 0; i<= numItems; i++) {
        if ( i != $(this).index()){ // if the div is not selected 
             $(".detail").remove(i);//remove unnecessary div
        } 
    }
});
```

I do not know how to remove one element with **class ="detail"** by **index**, why  `$(".detail").remove(i);` can not be used? It is logical, isn't it?

Comment: `$(".detail").eq(i).remove();`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `.not()` filter at this context to ease your job,

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.detail', function() {
  $(".detail").not(this).remove();
});
```

There is no need to iterate over all the elements.

Comment: By 'not iterate', you mean 'not explicitly iterate'. This is just cleaner code, of course

Comment: @Obsidian Internally lot of iterations will happen, why we need to do it on our own by using plain loops? That is why I mentioned like that. :)

Comment: Yes, I was just making sure no one misunderstood. Good answer